# Bouncing Particles are unexpectedly overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been generating a set of bouncing orbs within **D3**. I've managed to get the system working according to the following rules:

- Orbs should slowly drift around
- Orbs should bounce off each other taking into account mass & momentum when doing so
- Orbs should not be able to leave the SVG area and should therefore bounce off the edges

I've managed to find a problem however and I can't figure out what could be causing it, every now and again the Orbs seem to get stuck - one node will get stuck to another, following it along rather than bouncing away and sometimes end up underneath, or over the top of another orb, which I thought should be impossible.

The overlapping logic is fairly simple, if the distance between the centers of 2 orbs is less than their combined radius they need to bounce:

```
// Calculate the distance between the centres of 
// two nodes, we don't have take the square root
// as we don't need it, and it's an expensive operation
var x = d.x - quad.point.x;
var y = d.y - quad.point.y;
var distance = x * x + y * y;

// Calculate the radius of each to determine how
// close they need to be to be considered touching
var radii = getSize(d) + getSize(quad.point);

// If the nodes appear to be touching then we need to move the points
if (distance < (radii * radii)) {
    // Overlapping
}
```

And if they bounce I calculate the angles and speeds at which they should bounce off, conserving the momentum which is a documented algorithm. I therefore can't figure out how two orbs could ever follow each other along?

```
function bounce_vectors(d1, d2) {

    // Calculate the angle at which the balls collide
    var dx = d1.x - d2.x;
    var dy = (d1.y - d2.y) * -1;
    var collisionAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

    // Calculate the speed of d1/d2
    var speed1 = Math.sqrt((d1.speedX * d1.speedX) + (d1.speedY * d1.speedY));
    var speed2 = Math.sqrt((d2.speedX * d2.speedX) + (d2.speedY * d2.speedY));

    // Get angles (in radians) for each ball, given current velocities
    var direction1 = Math.atan2(d1.speedY, d1.speedX);
    var direction2 = Math.atan2(d2.speedY, d2.speedX);

    // Rotate velocity vectors so we can plug into equation for conservation of momentum
    var rotatedVelocityX1 = speed1 * Math.cos(direction1 - collisionAngle);
    var rotatedVelocityY1 = speed1 * Math.sin(direction1 - collisionAngle);
    var rotatedVelocityX2 = speed2 * Math.cos(direction2 - collisionAngle);
    var rotatedVelocityY2 = speed2 * Math.sin(direction2 - collisionAngle);        

  // Update actual velocities using conservation of momentum
    var finalVelocityX1 = ((d1.size - d2.size) * rotatedVelocityX1 + (d2.size + d2.size) * rotatedVelocityX2) / (d1.size + d2.size);
    var finalVelocityX2 = ((d1.size + d1.size) * rotatedVelocityX1 + (d2.size - d1.size) * rotatedVelocityX2) / (d1.size + d2.size);

    // Y velocities remain constant
    var finalVelocityY1 = rotatedVelocityY1;
    var finalVelocityY2 = rotatedVelocityY2;

    // Rotate angles back again so the collision angle is preserved
    d1.speedX = Math.cos(collisionAngle) * finalVelocityX1 + Math.cos(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * finalVelocityY1;
    d1.speedY = Math.sin(collisionAngle) * finalVelocityX1 + Math.sin(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * finalVelocityY1;
    d2.speedX = Math.cos(collisionAngle) * finalVelocityX2 + Math.cos(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * finalVelocityY2;
    d2.speedY = Math.sin(collisionAngle) * finalVelocityX2 + Math.sin(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * finalVelocityY2;
};
```

```js
// Add an additional function to the string prototype
if (!String.prototype.format) {
    String.prototype.format = function () {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
              ? args[number]
              : match
            ;
        });
    };
}

d3.Orbs = function() {
   
 var width = 500;
 var height = 500;
 var maxSpeed = 10;
    var alpha = 0.026;

 var nodes = [
  { id: 1, name: "Software", size: 5, children: [
    { id: 4, name: "Bug" },
    { id: 5, name: "Feature" },
    { id: 6, name: "Build" }] 
  },
  { id: 2, name: "Scrum", size: 8, children: [
    { id: 7, name: "Sprint" },
    { id: 8, name: "Story" },
    { id: 9, name: "Story Point" }] 
  },
  { id: 3, name: "Resource", size: 12, children: [
    { id: 10, name: "Location" },
    { id: 11, name: "Team" },
    { id: 12, name: "Members" }] 
  },
        { id: 13, name: "A", size: 12 },
        { id: 14, name: "B", size: 9 },
        { id: 15, name: "C", size: 3 }
 ];

    /**
     * Initialize each of the nodes in the dataset to ensure
     * that the required positions and speeds exist in the data
     * for collision avoidance and applying gravity
     * @param {array} The collection of nodes from the raw data
     * @param {object} A bounding rectangle to restrict where the nodes can be placed
     */
    function initialize_nodes(nodes, bounds) {
        // Ensure each node has a random start location and speed
        nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
            d.x = Math.random() * bounds.right;
            d.y = Math.random() * bounds.bottom;
            d.speedX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * maxSpeed;
            d.speedY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 2 * maxSpeed;
        });
        
        /*nodes[0].x = 100;
        nodes[0].y = 100;
        nodes[0].speedX = 10;
        nodes[0].speedY = -10;
        nodes[0].size = 10;
        nodes[0].fill = 'red';
        
        nodes[1].x = 200;
        nodes[1].y = 400;
        nodes[1].speedX = -10;
        nodes[1].speedY = 40;
        nodes[1].size = 20;
        nodes[1].fill = 'steelblue';*/
    };
  
    // Initialize the nodes now
    initialize_nodes(nodes, {left: 0, top: 0, bottom: height, right: width});
        
 

 var force = d3.layout.force()
                        .alpha(alpha)
       .gravity(0)
       .charge(0)
       .nodes(nodes)
       .size([width, height])
       .on("tick", tick);

 var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
       .data(nodes)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
         .attr("class", "node")
                        .style('fill', function(d) { return d.fill; })
         .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return getSize(d); });
 
 function getSize(node) {
  return 5 * node.size;
 }

/**
 * Return a function that applies gravity to an individual node
 * @param {number} The alpha or kinetic energy currently in the system
 * @returns {function} The funtion that applies gravity to each individual node
 */
function gravity(alpha) {
    
    /**
     * Update the position and speed of the node based upon it's current location
     * @param {Object} The data node that is being moved
     */
    return function(d) {
     var radius = getSize(d);
        
        // If the node is attempting to move off screen then invert the speed
        // on that axis to bring it back into scope
        if ((d.x - radius) < 0) d.speedX = Math.abs(d.speedX);
        if ((d.x + radius) > width) d.speedX = -1 * Math.abs(d.speedX);
        if ((d.y - radius) < 0) d.speedY = -1 * Math.abs(d.speedY);
        if ((d.y + radius) > height) d.speedY = Math.abs(d.speedY);
        
        // Set the current position of the node
        d.x = d.x + (d.speedX * alpha);
        d.y = d.y + (-1 * d.speedY * alpha);
        
        // Apply some extra protection - if the node has moved off the screen
        // then get it back again rather than waiting for it's speed
        d.x = Math.min(Math.max(d.x, 0 + radius), width - radius);
        d.y = Math.min(Math.max(d.y, 0 + radius), height - radius);
    };
}

/**
 * Update the positions of nodes whenever we recieved a tick notification
 * from the force layout algorithm
 * @param {object} D3 tick event args
 */
function tick(e) {
 // Ensure that the Alpha never drops to 0
    // Note that on mobile devices this could be a big battery drain
    force.alpha(alpha);
      
    // Update the position of each node by applying a gravity function
    // and preventing any collisions of the nodes
    node.each(gravity(.51 * e.alpha))
        .each(function(d) { d.color = '#2B301C';})
        .each(function(d) { d.bounced = d.bounced || []; })
        .each(resolve_collisions(0.5))
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.color || '#2B301C'; });
};
    
function resolve_collisions(alpha) {
    
    // Build a quad tree from the nodes
    var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes);
   
    // http://www.exeneva.com/2012/06/multiple-balls-bouncing-and-colliding-example/
    function bounce_vectors(d1, d2) {
        
        // Calculate the angle at which the balls collide
        var dx = d1.x - d2.x;
        var dy = (d1.y - d2.y) * -1;
        var collisionAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        
        // Calculate the speed of d1/d2
        var speed1 = Math.sqrt((d1.speedX * d1.speedX) + (d1.speedY * d1.speedY));
        var speed2 = Math.sqrt((d2.speedX * d2.speedX) + (d2.speedY * d2.speedY));
          
        // Get angles (in radians) for each ball, given current velocities
        var direction1 = Math.atan2(d1.speedY, d1.speedX);
        var direction2 = Math.atan2(d2.speedY, d2.speedX);
       
        // Rotate velocity vectors so we can plug into equation for conservation of momentum
        var rotatedVelocityX1 = speed1 * Math.cos(direction1 - collisionAngle);
        var rotatedVelocityY1 = speed1 * Math.sin(direction1 - collisionAngle);
        var rotatedVelocityX2 = speed2 * Math.cos(direction2 - collisionAngle);
        var rotatedVelocityY2 = speed2 * Math.sin(direction2 - collisionAngle);        
        
      // Update actual velocities using conservation of momentum
        var finalVelocityX1 = ((d1.size - d2.size) * rotatedVelocityX1 + (d2.size + d2.size) * rotatedVelocityX2) / (d1.size + d2.size);
        var finalVelocityX2 = ((d1.size + d1.size) * rotatedVelocityX1 + (d2.size - d1.size) * rotatedVelocityX2) / (d1.size + d2.size);
        
        // Y velocities remain constant
        var finalVelocityY1 = rotatedVelocityY1;
        var finalVelocityY2 = rotatedVelocityY2;
        
        // Rotate angles back again so the collision angle is preserved
        d1.speedX = Math.cos(collisionAngle) * finalVelocityX1 + Math.cos(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * finalVelocityY1;
        d1.speedY = Math.sin(collisionAngle) * finalVelocityX1 + Math.sin(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * finalVelocityY1;
        d2.speedX = Math.cos(collisionAngle) * finalVelocityX2 + Math.cos(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * finalVelocityY2;
        d2.speedY = Math.sin(collisionAngle) * finalVelocityX2 + Math.sin(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * finalVelocityY2;
    };
    
    return function(d, i) {
       
       
        

        
        // Using a quad tree to speed things up visit each pair of nodes
        quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                     
            // Compare points together - but don't compare the
            // current point to itself
            if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
                                     
                // Calculate the distance between the centres of 
                // two nodes, we don't have take the square root
                // as we don't need it, and it's an expensive operation
                var x = d.x - quad.point.x;
                var y = d.y - quad.point.y;
                var distance = x * x + y * y;
            
                // Calculate the radius of each to determine how
                // close they need to be to be considered touching
                var radii = getSize(d) + getSize(quad.point);

                // If the nodes appear to be touching then we need to move the points
                if (distance < (radii * radii)) {
                    
                    // If these items have already bounced then continue
                    if(d.bounced.indexOf(quad.point) !== -1) {
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    d.bounced.push(quad.point);
                    quad.point.bounced.push(d);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        var index = d.bounced.indexOf(quad.point);
                        d.bounced.splice(index, 1);
                        index = quad.point.bounced.indexOf(d);
                        quad.point.bounced.splice(index);
                    }, 5250);
                    
                    d.color = 'red';
                    quad.point.color = 'red';
                    bounce_vectors(d, quad.point);
            }
      }
    });
  };
}



 force.start();       

};

d3.Orbs();
```

```css
.node {
    fill: #77B72B;
    stroke: #2B301C;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}
svg {
    background: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: AFAICT this can happen: 2 colliding balls' velocities could either have really low magnitudes or nearly parallel directions. Then your computed bounce velocities might not be enough to make them "escape" their overlap in the next tick. If so, then there would need to be a final step that checks and — if necessary — scales up the magnitude of the vectors `[d1.speedX, d1.speedY]` and `[d2.speedX, d2.speedY]` to ensure that in the next tick they'll be far enough apart to avoid lingering overlaps. As a proof of concept, you can simply `Math.max(d1.speedX, radii/2)` and see if the problem stops.

Comment: Well... to be accurate, it's not as simple as `Math.max(d1.speedX, radii/2)` because that doesn't preserve the sign of `d1.speedX`, so it has to use `Math.abs` too.

Comment: @meetamit that kinda makes sense. You may notice I've got a store of pairs and ignore bounces between them as they were being over processed and taking their original vector. A timeout is supposed to prevent that but would explain why really show orbs don't work. I'll give that a try tomorrow

Comment: @meetamit: It might work, it's difficult to tell. The problem is because energy is conserved, this acceleration causes the entire thing to constantly speed up. As the orbs increase their velocity, they overlap more during an impact (the problem I'm trying to prevent) which makes them have to go that bit faster.